# How do I take a slice of a list (A sublist) in scheme?

Tags: lisp, scheme

Given a list, how would I select a new list, containing a slice of the original list (Given offset and number of elements) ?

#### EDIT:

Good suggestions so far. Isn't there something specified in one of the SRFI's? This appears to be a very fundamental thing, so I'm surprised that I need to implement it in user-land.

Comment: I just want to put in my recommendation for Nathan Sanders's answer, it's definitely a better use of SRFIs than the other submissions. Besides, that would have been the answer I'd have written. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following code will do what you want:

```
(define get-n-items
    (lambda (lst num)
        (if (> num 0)
            (cons (car lst) (get-n-items (cdr lst) (- num 1)))
            '()))) ;'

(define slice
    (lambda (lst start count)
        (if (> start 1)
            (slice (cdr lst) (- start 1) count)
            (get-n-items lst count))))
```

Example:

```
> (define l '(2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)) ;'
()
> l
(2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
> (slice l 2 4)
(3 4 5 6)
>
```

Comment: There's a typo in get-n-items - The else-part of the if-form needs a quote. Can you edit that?

Answer (score 14):

Strangely, `slice` is not provided with [SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html) but you can make it shorter by using SRFI-1's [`take` and `drop`](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#take):

```
(define (slice l offset n)
  (take (drop l offset) n))
```

I thought that one of the extensions I've used with Scheme, like the PLT Scheme library or Swindle, would have this built-in, but it doesn't seem to be the case. It's not even defined in the new R6RS libraries.

Comment: Keep in mind that with this answer, you can't do `(slice '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0) 3 9)` because it'll run out of list. You actually have to pass it an offset-from-start and length-of-final-list instead of two offsets from zero. You also can't do `(slice l 3 -4)` (which a python user would expect to mean "take everything from the third to the fourth-to-last element of list l"). A real slice function would be quite a bit more complicated.

Comment: You are thinking of Python slice, which uses offset1, offset2. For the offset, number-of-elements approach, this is the right answer: "take 9 elements starting at the 3rd" *should* give you fewer than 9 if the list runs out. (I personally think Python's approach is better, but that's not what the question is.)

Answer (score 7):

You can try this function:

> **subseq** *sequence start &optional end*

The *start* parameter is your offset. The *end* parameter can be easily turned into the number of elements to grab by simply adding start + number-of-elements.

A small bonus is that **subseq** works on all sequences, this includes not only lists but also string and vectors.

Edit: It seems that not all lisp implementations have subseq, though it will do the job just fine if you have it.

Comment: Is subseq a CL function? It doesn't appear to be part of PLT-Scheme at least.

Comment: Gauche has it: http://practical-scheme.net/wiliki/arcxref?subseq. don't know about others.

Comment: Weird. I read about it Paradigms of AI and it was presented as part of the standard. I guess I'm not sure which one of the standards. :P Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: In Racket's **data/collection** there's `subsequence` and `subsequence*`

Answer (score 3):

```
(define (sublist list start number)
  (cond ((> start 0) (sublist (cdr list) (- start 1) number))
        ((> number 0) (cons (car list)
                      (sublist (cdr list) 0 (- number 1))))
        (else '())))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
    (define (slice l offset length)
      (if (null? l)
        l
        (if (> offset 0)
            (slice (cdr l) (- offset 1) length)
            (if (> length 0)
                (cons (car l) (slice (cdr l) 0 (- length 1)))
                '()))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my implementation of `slice` that uses a proper tail call

```
(define (slice a b xs (ys null))
  (cond ((> a 0) (slice (- a 1) b (cdr xs) ys))
        ((> b 0) (slice a (- b 1) (cdr xs) (cons (car xs) ys)))
        (else (reverse ys))))

(slice 0 3 '(A B C D E F G)) ;=> '(A B C)
(slice 2 4 '(A B C D E F G)) ;=> '(C D E F)
```